# Easy way to upload mp3 to a public link that automatically plays when the url is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mp3, dropbox, twilio

For a ruby on rails twilio app, I simply need to upload an mp3 to a url that will automatically play when someone visits the url.

I tried using dropbox, but when a public link is created, it no longer automatically plays the mp3 file.

I am fine with using another file sharing service, etc.  OR if there is an easy ruby API that will do this, that will work too.

Thanks for all of the help.

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use Amazon S3 for this.  You should have no problem finding a library to allow you to upload to S3.

The reason I use S3 is because it's super cheap for the amount I'm using it, and Twilio uses Amazon Web Services, so it may help with network latency, though I have no way to confirm that.

Comment: Yea, sorry I should have resolved this question.  I decided to go with amazon.  It works!

Answer (score 0):

This [SoundCloud API Ruby Wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/ruby-api-wrapper/wiki) might fit the bill of what you're looking for.